# Android - 4 in a row animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm creating a "4 in a row" game for `Android`.
Basically, I'd like to create a `falling down animation` when the user add a new circle.

So far, this is the layout I inflate to create a row (with 4 columns at the moment):

```
    <com.fourinarow.widgets.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/tile_1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.fourinarow.widgets.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/tile_2"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.fourinarow.widgets.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/tile_3"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.fourinarow.widgets.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/tile_4"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the user click on a cell (A `CiurcleView`), I just set the color. What I'd like to do is to add a `falling down` animation.

Is there an easy way to achieve that ?

Comment: What is CiurcleView extended?

Comment: Hello. `CircleView` is extending a `View`. Basically, it's just a circle drawn in a canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a smoother way to achieve that:

```
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, posX, 0, posY);
slide.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
slide.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
circle.startAnimation(slide);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Handler and animate the y intercept of the View every 50 millisecond using the postDelayed method of the handler.

sample:

```
private float movey;
private View view;
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      movey = (float)view.getY() + 0.1;
      view.setY(movey);

 }
}
};
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50);
```